# Digital compatibility of logic gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, electrical, homework

I started an applied electronics course at my university and my teacher assigned us this assignment after a lecture on how to check the compatibility of two or more gates:

- Output electrical parameters: $$ V_{OL}=0.37V \space V_{OH}=3.76V \space I_{OL}=24mA \space I_{OH}=-24mA $$
- Input el. par.: $$ V_{IL}=0.9V \space V_{IH}=3.15V \space I_{IL}=-1 \mu A \space I_{IH}=1 \mu A $$
- The output drives:

  - 4 inputs
  - a resistance of 1kOhm connected to Vdd = 5V

I have to check the digital compatibility, she suggested to compare the voltages  and calculate and verify the currents.

I did the comparison of the voltages, I checked that Voh>Vih and Vol

My problem was on the currents. I split the problem in the two cases: H output voltage, L output voltage. 
I am not sure on how to use the '4 inputs' and the 'resistance connected to Vdd' information

Comment: How you _could_ do it is something I could conceivably weigh in on, but how you're _supposed_ to do it is not.

Comment: hmm, sounds like you didn't listen to the lecture on how to check the compatibility of two or more gates, I would expect that how you're supposed to do it is included in that. Did you take notes? Hint, what is the output guarranteed to drive into the 4 gate load and resistor in parallel? Does that meet the input requirements?

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Answer (score 1):

You say you've already checked that the voltages are compatible, so no check the current.  The output can only source or sink some maximum current for the other specs to be valid.  Each input requires some current to hold it in a guaranteed logic high or low condition.  Overall, you have to make sure that the output can source/sink at least the current required by all inputs together.

You have all the values essentially sitting on a silver platter.  Go do the math.

Comment: Ok but do I have to consider the resistance connected to Vdd in both high and low conditions? Or only in one of the two. I have this doubt simply because the slides it tells something about the loads that's not clear